# Paypal API instead of IPN to Salesforce

Tags: paypal, salesforce, paypal-ipn

I have everything configured for PayPal to send transactions as they happen into Salesforce via an IPN listener.  However, since another site is resetting the IPN via the API, I don't have access to the data stream.  (Yes, they refuse to echo it to me)

So, I'm planning to convert to use the API instead of relying on the IPN listener.

Before I do, I have some quick questions that will help prevent me from heading down a dead end...

- Will PayPal allow each transaction to be sent two places (one via IPN and the other to me via the API)?
- Will the API deliver transaction data directly or does it come through IPN?
- Is the payload data the same (ignoring that the formatting is different, JSON and all)?
- Is this a path that is bound trouble?

Thanks for the expert insights...

Steve

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing how the API and IPN work. IPN is a push notice, meaning that PayPal will contact you when a payment is made or changes. The API, by contrast, requires you to submit a request to PayPal, which then gets you a response.

You can get almost all the data IPN submits by using the [GetTransactionDetails API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/), but that requires that you already have a transaction ID.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that.  Realizing it's a pull approach, an I get transactions through the API that have already been pushed to via IPN?

Comment: They probably have already been pushed via IPN, yes. IPN is usually within a few seconds of the action.

Comment: IPN is an asynchronous push process. The speed/successful completion of that process is completely irrelevant to/unrelated to any syncchronous API interactions, whether payment APIs (such as a DoEC API) or reporting APIs (such as GetTransactionDetails). Once a payment is created, you can call GetTansactionDetails on it irrespective of the use, or state, of IPN for that transaction.

Comment: Thank you but my question is on a different bent...That is, will PayPal allow one transaction to be sent out by IPN and later be requested through the API?  In other words, does sending a transaction by IPN prevent it from also being accessed though the API?

Comment: @sberley The simple answer is no. You can request that data anytime via the API